# Issue Deserializing LocalDateTime: Jackson InvalidFormatException

Tags: java, date

I'm encountering a problem deserializing LocalDateTime in my Spring Boot application. Below is the relevant code.

Front-end:

```
update(lancamento: Lancamento): Promise<Lancamento> {
      const headers = new HttpHeaders()
        .set('Authorization', this.chave)
        .set('Content-Type', 'application/json');

        this.conversorDeData([lancamento]);

        return firstValueFrom(this.http.put<any>(`${this.url}/${lancamento.codigo}`,
      lancamento, { headers }));
    }

    findByCode(codigo: number): Promise<Lancamento> {
      const headers = new HttpHeaders()
        .set('Authorization', this.chave);

      return this.http.get(`${this.url}/${codigo}`,
        { headers })
        .toPromise()
        .then((response: any) => {
          const lancamento = response as Lancamento;

          this.conversorDeData([lancamento]);

          return lancamento;
        })
        .catch((error: any) => {
          console.error('Erro ao buscar lançamento por código: ', error);
          throw error;
        });
    }

//Se os atributos forem do tipo Date
conversorDeData(lancamentos: Lancamento[]){
  for(const lancamento of lancamentos){
    if(lancamento.dataVencimento && isValid(lancamento.dataVencimento)){
      lancamento.dataVencimento = new Date(format(lancamento.dataVencimento, 'dd/MM/yyyy'));
    }
    if(lancamento.dataPagamento && isValid(lancamento.dataPagamento)){
      lancamento.dataPagamento = new Date(format(lancamento.dataPagamento, 'dd/MM/yyyy'));
    }

  }
}
```

Back-end: Lancamento class:

```
package com.algaworks.algamoney_api.domain.model;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFormat;
import jakarta.persistence.*;
import jakarta.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat;

import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.Objects;

@Entity
@Table(name = "lancamento")
public class Lancamento {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer codigo;

    @NotNull
    private String descricao;

    @Column(name = "data_vencimento")
    @JsonFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy")
    private LocalDateTime dataVencimento;

    @Column(name = "data_pagamento")
    @JsonFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy")
    private LocalDateTime dataPagamento;

    @NotNull
    private BigDecimal valor;
    private String observacao;

    @NotNull
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private TipoLancamento tipo;

    @NotNull
    @ManyToOne // vários lançamentos podem estar em uma categoria
    @JoinColumn(name = "codigo_categoria")
    private Categoria categoria;

    @NotNull
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "codigo_pessoa")
    private Pessoa pessoa;

    public Integer getCodigo() {
        return codigo;
    }

    public void setCodigo(Integer codigo) {
        this.codigo = codigo;
    }

    public String getDescricao() {
        return descricao;
    }

    public void setDescricao(String descricao) {
        this.descricao = descricao;
    }

    public LocalDateTime getDataVencimento() {
        return dataVencimento;
    }

    public void setDataVencimento(LocalDateTime dataVencimento) {
        this.dataVencimento = dataVencimento;
    }

    public LocalDateTime getDataPagamento() {
        return dataPagamento;
    }

    public void setDataPagamento(LocalDateTime dataPagamento) {
        this.dataPagamento = dataPagamento;
    }

    public BigDecimal getValor() {
        return valor;
    }

    public void setValor(BigDecimal valor) {
        this.valor = valor;
    }

    public String getObservacao() {
        return observacao;
    }

    public void setObservacao(String observacao) {
        this.observacao = observacao;
    }

    public TipoLancamento getTipo() {
        return tipo;
    }

    public void setTipo(TipoLancamento tipo) {
        this.tipo = tipo;
    }

    public Categoria getCategoria() {
        return categoria;
    }

    public void setCategoria(Categoria categoria) {
        this.categoria = categoria;
    }

    public Pessoa getPessoa() {
        return pessoa;
    }

    public void setPessoa(Pessoa pessoa) {
        this.pessoa = pessoa;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        Lancamento that = (Lancamento) o;
        return codigo.equals(that.codigo);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(codigo);
    }
}
```

ResumoLancamento class:

```
package com.algaworks.algamoney_api.repository.projection;

import com.algaworks.algamoney_api.domain.model.TipoLancamento;

import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;

/**
 * 7.1. Implementando projeção de lançamento*/

public class ResumoLancamento {

    private Integer codigo;
    private String descricao;
    private LocalDateTime dataVencimento;
    private LocalDateTime dataPagamento;
    private BigDecimal valor;
    private TipoLancamento tipo;
    private String categoria;
    private String pessoa;

    public ResumoLancamento(Integer codigo, String descricao, LocalDateTime dataVencimento, LocalDateTime dataPagamento, BigDecimal valor, TipoLancamento tipo, String categoria, String pessoa) {
        this.codigo = codigo;
        this.descricao = descricao;
        this.dataVencimento = dataVencimento;
        this.dataPagamento = dataPagamento;
        this.valor = valor;
        this.tipo = tipo;
        this.categoria = categoria;
        this.pessoa = pessoa;
    }

    public Integer getCodigo() {
        return codigo;
    }

    public void setCodigo(Integer codigo) {
        this.codigo = codigo;
    }

    public String getDescricao() {
        return descricao;
    }

    public void setDescricao(String descricao) {
        this.descricao = descricao;
    }

    public LocalDateTime getDataVencimento() {
        return dataVencimento;
    }

    public void setDataVencimento(LocalDateTime dataVencimento) {
        this.dataVencimento = dataVencimento;
    }

    public LocalDateTime getDataPagamento() {
        return dataPagamento;
    }

    public void setDataPagamento(LocalDateTime dataPagamento) {
        this.dataPagamento = dataPagamento;
    }

    public BigDecimal getValor() {
        return valor;
    }

    public void setValor(BigDecimal valor) {
        this.valor = valor;
    }

    public TipoLancamento getTipo() {
        return tipo;
    }

    public void setTipo(TipoLancamento tipo) {
        this.tipo = tipo;
    }

    public String getCategoria() {
        return categoria;
    }

    public void setCategoria(String categoria) {
        this.categoria = categoria;
    }

    public String getPessoa() {
        return pessoa;
    }

    public void setPessoa(String pessoa) {
        this.pessoa = pessoa;
    }
}
```

Problem:

com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidFormatException: Cannot deserialize value of type `java.time.LocalDateTime` from String "10/01/2024": Failed to deserialize java.time.LocalDateTime: (java.time.format.DateTimeParseException) Text '10/01/2024' could not be parsed: Unable to obtain LocalDateTime from TemporalAccessor: {},ISO resolved to 2024-01-10 of type java.time.format.Parsed
at [Source: (org.springframework.util.StreamUtils$NonClosingInputStream); line: 1, column: 63] (through reference chain: com.algaworks.algamoney_api.domain.model.Lancamento["dataVencimento"])

in console.log() of lancamentos, the attributes "dataVencimento" and "dataPagamento" are in the format "dd/MM/yyyy".

I suspect a date format issue during deserialization. Despite updating both front-end and back-end code, the problem persists. I believe the problem is with the client, I d no.

1. How can I fix the InvalidFormatException when deserializing LocalDateTime from a string in my Spring Boot application?
2. Are there specific configurations or adjustments required for correct LocalDateTime serialization and deserialization?

Any guidance or suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks!

I did everything with theDataconverter() method but I still wasn't successful.

```
conversorDeData(lancamentos: Lancamento[]){
  for(const lancamento of lancamentos){
    if(lancamento.dataVencimento && isValid(lancamento.dataVencimento)){
      lancamento.dataVencimento = new Date(format(lancamento.dataVencimento, 'dd/MM/yyyy'));
    }
    if(lancamento.dataPagamento && isValid(lancamento.dataPagamento)){
      lancamento.dataPagamento = new Date(format(lancamento.dataPagamento, 'dd/MM/yyyy'));
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: The gist is that you don't transmit a Time, so use `LocalDate` instead of `LocalDateTime`.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this issue, you can do one of the following:

Option 1: Adjust the JSON date format
Change the date format in your JSON payload to match the pattern "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss" or any format that is directly compatible with LocalDateTime. For example:

```
{
  "codigo": 1,
  "descricao": "Sample description",
  "dataVencimento": "2024-01-10T00:00:00",
  "dataPagamento": "2024-01-10T00:00:00",
  "valor": 100.0,
  "observacao": "Sample observation",
  "tipo": "SAMPLE_TYPE",
  "categoria": {
    "codigo": 1
  },
  "pessoa": {
    "codigo": 1
  }
}
```

Option 2: Use @JsonDeserialize to specify a custom deserialization format
You can annotate the LocalDateTime fields in your Lancamento class with @JsonDeserialize to specify a custom deserialization format. For example:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonDeserialize;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jsr310.deser.LocalDateTimeDeserializer;
// other imports...

@Entity
@Table(name = "lancamento")
public class Lancamento {
    // ... other fields

    @Column(name = "data_vencimento")
    @JsonDeserialize(using = LocalDateTimeDeserializer.class)
    private LocalDateTime dataVencimento;

    @Column(name = "data_pagamento")
    @JsonDeserialize(using = LocalDateTimeDeserializer.class)
    private LocalDateTime dataPagamento;

    // ... other methods
}
```

Remember to adjust the de-serialization format or the date format in the JSON payload to ensure they align correctly. Choose an approach that best fits your requirements and coding practices.

Option 3:The issue arises because LocalDateTime in Java doesn't have a direct formatter for the pattern "dd/MM/yyyy" that includes both date and time components. You might need to change the type of these fields to LocalDate if you're only interested in the date component.

```
//...

@Column(name = "data_vencimento")
@JsonFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy")
private LocalDate dataVencimento;

@Column(name = "data_pagamento")
@JsonFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy")
private LocalDate dataPagamento;

//...

public LocalDate getDataVencimento() {
    return dataVencimento;
}

public void setDataVencimento(LocalDate dataVencimento) {
    this.dataVencimento = dataVencimento;
}

public LocalDate getDataPagamento() {
    return dataPagamento;
}

public void setDataPagamento(LocalDate dataPagamento) {
    this.dataPagamento = dataPagamento;
}
```